# Motor for a self drivig handcart

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

I want to build a self driving handcart.
The car should be able move round about 80kg with a speed of 6km/h.
My idea is to use a 12 volt dc motor on the back axis for the drive and a servo motor on the front for the steering.

My question for the drive motor is can I use just anyone who has enough power and use pwm to slow them down, because there are motors with gears build in.

Or are this not enough information to provide a satisfying answer and should I construct the chassi first so that I know the wheel diameter.

Thx for your advice.

Comment: This has been asked here and on the Engineering Stack so many times now - must be a student project...

Comment: Start with the physics. Once you know both the power and energy requirement, you can think about motor and battery and both electric and mechanical drive systems.

Comment: Nah, just a lot of people with the same product idea. We had a "stint" in the Netherlands until a fatal accident: https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-45717871